# Android - how to get a url/link from an API (rottentomatoes) JSON

Tags: java, android, json, api, networking

This is a part of my code, In my code I am getting the "title" and the "synopsis" of a movie, but the "profile" part doesn't work for some reason, and i cannot get the img link from the website, here's the [website api](http://developer.rottentomatoes.com/docs), thanks for you're help.

```
@Override


    protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
                super.onPostExecute(response);

                try {
                    // convert the String response to a JSON object
                    JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);

                    // fetch the array of movies in the response
                    JSONArray jArray = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("movies");

                    // add each movie's title to a list
                    movieTitles = new ArrayList<String>();
                    movieSynopsis = new ArrayList<String>();

                    movieImgUrl= new ArrayList<String>(); // **problematic**

                    for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject movie = jArray.getJSONObject(i);                 

                            movieTitles.add(movie.getString("title"));

                            movieSynopsis.add(movie.getString("synopsis"));

                            movieImgUrl.add(movie.getString("profile")); // **problematic**


                    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your code as

```
 movieImgUrl.add(movie.getJSONObject("posters").getString("profile"));
```

This is because `posters` is a `JSONObject` and the image links are inside that JSONObject.